# White space between Expanded widgets

Tags: flutter

Some Flex values create white space between Expanded widgets, as I understand it is the remainder of the calculations.

For example:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 6,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to make these widgets take up all the available space.
The whole problem is that the flex values change during animation and this white line blinks.

Thanks!

Comment: i prefer `layoutBuilder`

Comment: Can you add an image for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems it is coming from `border` of `Container`,

[Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288#issuecomment-668795963) is still open.

[image]

here is the widget

```
 Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text("Section A"),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              child: Text("Section B"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add SizedBox() in between your expanded Widget like below:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
   SizedBox(
     height: 25,)
      Expanded(
        flex: 6,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```