# Is there a way to avoid getting the canvas color around the text fields?

Tags: flutter

I just started learning Flutter, and I was practicing when i noticed that the background color of the text fields is inherited from the canvas color. However, even after establishing a new color for the text, overriding the previous one, there's a thin colored line on the borders of the widget.

I could just change the color of the canvas, but i'd like to use it to determine the background of the screen or the background of future widgets. Is there any way to get rid of these lines? I've tried playing with the scaffold widget and it's background too, but i had no success.

Here's the code before changing the text's background color:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted
        canvasColor: Colors.blue,
        // scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white
      ),
      home: MyLoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyLoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyLoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final"

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          body:
          Column(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children:
              [
                SizedBox(height: 80),

                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 375,
                  decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow:
                        [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                            spreadRadius: 2,
                            blurRadius: 3,
                            offset: Offset(0, 0)
                          )
                        ]
                    ),
                  child:
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children:
                        [
                          SizedBox(height: 1),
                          Row(
                            children:
                              [
                                Container(
                                    // color: Colors.white,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                    child:
                                    Icon(
                                        Icons.email_rounded,
                                        size: 20
                                    )
                                ),

                                Material(
                                  child:
                                    Container(
                                      // color: Colors.white,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                      child:
                                      Text('Email',
                                            style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            // backgroundColor: Colors.white
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),

                          Divider(color: Colors.black),

                          Row(
                              children:
                              [
                                Container(
                                  // color: Colors.white,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                  child:
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.lock,
                                      size: 20
                                    )
                                ),

                                Material(
                                  child:
                                  Container(
                                    // color: Colors.white,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                    child:
                                    Text('Password',
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          // backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 1),
                        ]
                    )
                ),


              ]
          )
    );
  }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Here's the code after changing the text's background color:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted
        canvasColor: Colors.blue,
        // scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white
      ),
      home: MyLoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyLoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyLoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final"

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          body:
          Column(
            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children:
              [
                SizedBox(height: 80),

                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 375,
                  decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow:
                        [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                            spreadRadius: 2,
                            blurRadius: 3,
                            offset: Offset(0, 0)
                          )
                        ]
                    ),
                  child:
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children:
                        [
                          SizedBox(height: 1),
                          Row(
                            children:
                              [
                                Container(
                                    // color: Colors.white,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                    child:
                                    Icon(
                                        Icons.email_rounded,
                                        size: 20
                                    )
                                ),

                                Material(
                                  child:
                                    Container(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                      child:
                                      Text('Email',
                                            style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            backgroundColor: Colors.white
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),

                          Divider(color: Colors.black),

                          Row(
                              children:
                              [
                                Container(
                                  // color: Colors.white,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                  child:
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.lock,
                                      size: 20
                                    )
                                ),

                                Material(
                                  child:
                                  Container(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left : 10.0),
                                    child:
                                    Text('Password',
                                          style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        )
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 1),
                        ]
                    )
                ),


              ]
          )
    );
  }
}
```

And the result (with the lines i'd like to remove):

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you include an image of the the ui that you like to archive?

Comment: It would be just that plain white rectangle, but without the thing blue lines that can be seen contouring "Email" and "Password"

Comment: You  can check my answer, hope this is issue of your widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that is actually working! Following what "@Yeasin Sheik" contributed with, i did some tests and i had success. As he said, the color of the container border had to be set to white too, but the key part was to set the width to 0.

However, both parameters are needed. When i only established the color, the lines were still there, and when i only set the width to 0, they kept showing up. But with both of them, poof!, gone.

Hope this helps until they solve the Github Issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is coming from the border of Container, To remove thin colored line on the borders of the widget, call `border`.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288#issuecomment-668795963) is still open.

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
          child: Text('Email',
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.grey,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              )),
        ),
```

[another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68549086/10157127)

Comment: I'm afraid the solucion doesn't seem to work. I may try with different widgets to see if its an only container issue tho. Thx!

Comment: I'm aware of thin line this issue and solved it this way. Let me know if you still stuck. Do flutter clean and restart the app, sometimes everything runs from cache.

Comment: I got it after working around what you said, thank you so much!